# how to afix this hhmmss problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I was doing window services where I'm generating txt files in target path based on some details from a database but I have a problem the service is running too fast!

I was getting same file name in the place of sec variation required so that i can avoid duplicates over there.

code :

```
using (transactionscope scope = new transactionscope ) 
{
  string nowtime = datetime.now.today.tostring(HHMMss) // it was working fine 
}
```

file should be generates by specific file naming convention !! ex:hhmmss >>> no millisecond
can any one give me exclusive ideas how to face this part?

Comment: just an aside but you may need to rethink your solution if you're using a timestamp to avoid duplicates. You will end up with duplicates if your service runs for more than 24 hours, or when daylight savings time kicks in, or someone changes the time on the system. Why don't you just use a GUID to uniquely identify the file ?

Answer (score 3):

You can add milliseconds to the filename:

```
string nowtime = datetime.Now.Today.ToString("HHmmssfff");
```

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

A few notes about the code you posted:

1. `MM` is for months, not minutes. You should use lower case mm.
2. The parameter that `ToString` takes is a string.
3. Your code wouldn't compile as it is not correctly cased. Please use code that *can* be directly used in the future.

---

Update:

Seeing as you *have* to use this format, the only other choice is to "slow down" the service.

Adding a:

```
Thread.Wait(1000);
```

In the right place (end of loop?) could do the trick.

Alternatively, you can change your code to append to a file if you are still within the same second.

Comment: no we cant .!! file should be generates by specific file naming convention !! ex:hhmmss  >>> no millisecond

Comment: @pubby - Why didn't you post that in your question? This is not something we can guess. Please edit your question and add this very important detail.

Comment: my doubt ...!!! we can relay on thread !! i mean it will provide exact  output required !!

Comment: @pubby -- could you rephrase that last comment? I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: i mean to say that ... thread.sleep will gives wrong output .!!

Comment: @pubby - thanks for rephrasing. That makes sense. Why exactly will that give you the wrong output?

Comment: @pubby - Could you please, in your question, say _exectly_ what the constraints are? Why would sleeping give the wrong output? What other constraints do you have?

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that you are creating multiple files with the same name (multiple files in the same second), then I would take the time out to the milliseconds.  You can do this with:

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("HHmmssfff");
```

The fff denotes the three places to the right of the decimal (thousandths of a second).